# Saving two related models using model forms

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Here are two models - Property and Developer:

```
class Property(models.Model):
    property_type = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Apartment')
    specifications = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='Basic')
    built_up_area = models.FloatField(max_length=6, null=False)
    total_area = models.FloatField(null=False)
    number_of_bedrooms = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=1)
    number_of_bathrooms = models.CharField(max_length=3, default=1)
    number_of_parking_spaces = models.CharField(max_length=2, default=0)
    address_line_one = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    address_line_two = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)
    pin_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False)
    developer = models.ForeignKey('Developer')

    connectivity = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)
    neighborhood_quality = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.property_type


class Developer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

And here is its corresponding form:

```
class PropertyForm(ModelForm):
    developer = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Property
        fields = [
            'built_up_area',
            'total_area',
            'number_of_bedrooms',
            'number_of_bathrooms',
            'number_of_parking_spaces',
            'address_line_one',
            'address_line_two',
            'city',
            'state',
            'pin_code',
        ]
        widgets = {
            'number_of_bedrooms': forms.Select(
                choices=((1, 1,), (2, 2), (3, 3)), ),
            'number_of_bathrooms': forms.Select(
                choices=((1, 1,), (2, 2), (3, 3)), ),
            'number_of_parking_spaces': forms.Select(
                choices=((1, 1,), (2, 2), (3, 3)), ),
            'developer': forms.TextInput(),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PropertyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.fields['address_line_two'].required = False,
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            AppendedText('built_up_area', 'sq ft'),
            AppendedText('total_area', 'sq ft'),
            'number_of_bedrooms',
            'number_of_bathrooms',
            'number_of_parking_spaces',
            'address_line_one',
            'address_line_two',
            'city',
            'state',
            'pin_code',
            'developer',
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('Submit', 'submit', css_class='btn-block')
            )
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        developer = self.cleaned_data['developer']
        developer, created = Developer.objects.get_or_create(name=developer)
        self.instance.developer = developer

        return super(PropertyForm, self).save()
```

What could be a better way to save related objects using a single form?

Are formsets to be used here? I read about them but couldn't get it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is optimal, but one thing to keep in mind is that your html- can contain several django-forms. In a way it may be useful to think of django forms as collections of formfields with additional functionality (validation etc...).
As a consequence you could have two regular ModelForms. One for Properties and one for Developers. in you view you instantiate both and hand them over to your template.

Said template may now contain something like this:

```
<form blahblub....>
Properties:
{{ propertyform.as_p }}

Developer:
{{ developerform.as_p }}
</form>
```

now, upon post your view can just bind the POST data to each of those djangoforms like:

```
propertyform = PropertyForm(request.POST)
developerform = DeveloperForm(request.POST)
```

within your view you can validate your forms as usual.
You may add some custom logic instead of just calling Form.save() if you want to process developerform first in oder to save it before you continue to use the created object as a FK when post processing propertyform.

With regards to (Model)Formsets: if you want to create several Properties for one common developer this may be useful. but you can deal with that once the basics work :)

Comment: Yes, I can surely do this. This is the solution I am currently using but this requires me to first save the related model (Developer) and then override the project form's save method to explicitly set the developer to the saved developer. I was wondering if django helps in solving this case because saving of related object through the same model is quite trivial.